# java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I was trying to connect a database to my Java program and 
I get the error

```
May 28, 2018 9:26:40 PM com.example.test main
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.example.test.main(test.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
    ... 15 more cast to java.lang.Long
```

my code is:

```
package com.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection c;
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company", "root", "root");
            c.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing everything and could not find a solution. Thanks in advance for helping.

[image]

Comment: What is driver version? and mysql server version?

Comment: What is the driver version and MySQL version?

Answer (score 1):

I think its issue with you mysql connector jar. Please verify that mysql-connector jar is there on your classpath.

If you are using maven then check mysql-connector-java artifact in pom.

Comment: It would give a classnotfoundexception, not a casting problem.